# C# MVC generic repository with custom column name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, generics, repository, design-patterns

How can I achieve something like the following?

```
public interface IGenericRepository 
{
    int id { get; }

    T GetById<T>() where T : class
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository 
{
    //Some code here

    public T GetById<T>(int tid) where T : class 
    { 
        return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
    }
 }
```

And I would like to use this as follows:

```
GenericRepository gr = new GenericRepository();
Category cat = gr.GetById<Category>(15);
```

Of course, in this usage, `tbl.id` in the GenericRepository gives me an error.

**SOLUTION**

```
public class IHasId
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericRepository
{
    int id { get; }

    T GetById<T>(int id) where T : IHasId;
}

public class GenericRepository : IGenericRepository
{
    public int id
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    } 

    public T GetById<T>(int id) where T : IHasId
    {
        return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
    }
}
```

And apart from these, DON'T forget to define this somewhere in your model:

```
public partial class Category : IHasId { }
```

And the usage is:

```
Repository rep = new Repository();
Category cat = rep.GetById<Category>(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class IHasId
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
    int id { get; }

    T GetById(int id);
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : IHasId
{
    public int id
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return from tbl in dataContext.GetTable<T> where tbl.id == tid select tbl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn!! I finally understood the problem, apart from these codes, I had to create a partial class for each entity I use. Say, I have Category table, I had to create a public partial Category with IBase inheritance!! Thanks dude!!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems here - the first is that the generic type you're matching is a class, but a class doesn't have a property called 'id'. You need to have your Category class implement an interface that exposes an 'id' property:

```
public interface IIdentity
{
    int identity { get; set; }
}

public class Category : IIdentity
{
    public int identity{ get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why you've exposed 'id' as a property on the IGenericRepository interface - surely this is supposed to be a parameter passed to the find method (as indicated by your implementation). You also need to change the restriction on the 'GetById' method from:

```
where T : class
```

to something like

```
where T : IIdentity
```

using the interface I've suggested above.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Dave. But the problem is that when I change where T : class to IIdentity, dataContext.GetTable<T> will not work since T works like a variable of table names in this context. Or I can't get this working, I dont know...

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you accept every class `where T : class`. A class don't have that property.

Create an abstract class or interface to make sure that this property exists and change `where T : class` to `where T : IHasIdProperty`.

Comment: But then when I use gr.GetById<Category>(15) it gives me an error which says it's not possible to convert Category to IhasIdProperty, @dknaack

Comment: Actually, @dknaack, when I change the where clause as where T : IHasID, then the dataContext.GetTable<T> will give me an error

Comment: theres a news answer with a changed repository.